# Sending Files via Web Services

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I need to create a web service method (and therefore the WSDL) that accepts files (e.g. jpeg image).

I've searched the internet and I can't find anything past about 2010 that is useful.

Can somebody tell me how best to serialise a file and pass it into a web service. Is there a better way than base64/uuencode the file?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: With a webservice you're stuck with base64 data. Better change to a REST service which can consume binary streams...

Answer (score 1):

The common practice I always use is to create byte[] parameters for the files. The web service stack will convert it to base64 and send it to the server.

Comment: I second this. In my project, we send PDFs back as a response as `Byte()` along with some technical stuff (response code, message, client identification, etc). So we wrapped this all in a class and return it like that.